# ASP.NET resource cannot be found in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view, resources

I created an MVC5 project where I originally had my resource files in the root of the project.
In my views I referenced "Resource.*name*", for example:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Resource.CreateButtonText, "Create")
```

I then decided to move my resource files to a folder called "Resources". My views then showed an error:

> The name 'Resource' does not exist in the current context

How do I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that a using statement can also be done in a view :

```
@using Resources
```

where Resources is the namespace configured in the properties of the resource-files (item "Custom Tool Namespace" in VS2017)

Comment: Seems like this could have been a comment to or edit on my answer :) Anyway, glad you fixed it.

Comment: Thx for your answer and comment ... I felt it was worth an answer, as this is the preferred solution in my opinion ... it saves a lot of "typing" in comparison to without the using-statement.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly what has happened here is that the Visual Studio designer has modified the namespace in the resource class to match the folder name.

Try changing:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Resource.CreateButtonText, "Create")
```

to:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Resource.CreateButtonText, "Create")
```

or add a `using` directive to your view:

```
@using Resources
```

Alternatively, if `Resource` is a .resx file, right click on the .resx file in Visual Studio and click Properties, and edit the namespace.